# Flex Drop Down List Binding Issue (or Bug?)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm using the MVC model in my flex project.

What I'd like is to bind a value object's class properties to a view mxml, then change that view by altering the value object.

What happens:

1. Set the selected value to 'c' - index 2
2. Add 'x,y,z,' before 'c'
3. Hit enter -> now index 5
4. Hit enter -> now index is -1
5. See 4.

Why does only the first update work ? I know I'm probably missing something obvious...

Edit: [Running Example](http://www.infochoice.com.au/distributions/flash2010/ichlabs/bugs/dropdown/Dropdown.html)

(P.S. first post and im not sure how to turn on MXML highlighting)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               creationComplete="created(event)"
               width="160" height="220">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            //===================================
            //     Pretend Value Object Class
            [Bindable] private var list:ArrayList = null;
            [Bindable] private var index:int = 0;
            //===================================

            protected function created(event:FlexEvent):void {
                ddValues.addEventListener(FlexEvent.ENTER, update);
                update();
            }

            private function update(... args):void {
                //note selected item

                trace("dropdown index: " + dd.selectedIndex);
                var s:String = dd.selectedItem as String;
                trace("selected item: " + s);
                //build new list from csv
                list = new ArrayList(ddValues.text.split(","));
                trace("new list: " + ddValues.text);
                trace("selected item: " + s);
                //if exists in new list, set value object index
                var newIndex:int = 0;
                if(list)
                list.toArray().forEach(function(ss:String, i:int, a:Array):void { 
                    if(s == ss) newIndex = i;; 
                });
                index = newIndex;
                trace("new index: " + index + "  (dropdown index: " + dd.selectedIndex + ")");
                trace("===");
            }


            protected function ddChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                trace("selected item: " + (dd.selectedItem as String) + "  (dropdown index: " + dd.selectedIndex + ")");
                trace("===");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel width="100%" height="100%" title="Drop Down Bug">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout gap="10" paddingLeft="10" paddingTop="10" paddingRight="10" paddingBottom="10"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:DropDownList id="dd" dataProvider="{list}" selectedIndex="@{index}" change="ddChange(event)"></s:DropDownList>
        <s:Label text="Label: {dd.selectedItem as String}" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
        <s:Label text="Code Index: {index}" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
        <s:Label text="DropDown Index: {dd.selectedIndex}" paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="5"/>
        <s:TextInput id="ddValues" text="a,b,c,d,e"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

And heres the output
Edited code and added traces. Heres the output that shows my problem:

```
dropdown index: -1
selected item: null
new list: a,b,c,d,e
selected item: null
new index: 0  (dropdown index: 0)
===
selected item: c  (dropdown index: 2)
===
dropdown index: 2
selected item: c
new list: a,b,x,y,z,c,d,e
selected item: c
new index: 5  (dropdown index: 5)
===
dropdown index: 5
selected item: c
new list: a,b,x,y,z,c,d,e
selected item: c
new index: 5  (dropdown index: 5)
===
dropdown index: -1
selected item: null
new list: a,b,x,y,z,c,d,e
selected item: null
new index: 0  (dropdown index: 0)
===
```

Comment: Hi! you wrote "now null somehow...", but what do the other traces display (selected item, list...)?

Comment: I read the statexment x100->null about 10 times, and I have no idea what it means.  Do you have a variable called x100?  I didn't see it defined.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship `Hit enter again x100 ` would mean hit enter again 100 times :)

Comment: You can't really daisy chain binding.  So, you can bind to an object; but not that objects properties.  It most likely works the first time due to grabbing the value on initial setup.  You could have your object dispatch 'change' events for each property.  Listen for that event and change the view that way.

Comment: So when you hit enter (100 times), exactly what is null at that point?

Comment: Yeah. I mean't all subsequent times you run update() sorry about that.

Comment: Edited for clarity. Also changed my 'GetItemIndex' to an 'iterate,compare and save index', same result though.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I didn't think I was daisy chaining bindings:

'index' <--two-way-bind--> dropdown index |

'list' one-way-bind--> dropdown list
? (edit: didn't realise there was no formatting in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see what's going on now.  When you replace the whole list, the selected item *will* be null, because the item that was selected was in the old list.  You'll need to store the selected item when it is selected, and then do the comparison against that stored item, not the current selected (null) item.

Note that what you're doing is in no way MVC, unless you've redefined MVC to mean "Model, View, and Controller are all the same thing."  In MVC, the model has no idea of the view, and the view only has access to *read* as much of the model as it needs to to display the data.  It does not have *write* access to the model.  That is the function of the controller.

Comment: "the selected item will be null, because the item that was selected was in the old list" I checked for that, before and after, I print 's' and it remains that same - because Strings are copied by value not by reference, correct ?

Comment: And yes, I think I have failed at MVC haha. Though I thought that was idea of flex binding, to bind the model to to view, but the logic that determines the values inside the model is done by the controller ?

Comment: "It does not have write access to the model" So essentially, two way binding breaks MVC ? Based off what you wrote, altering the value of 'index' causing a change to the drop down is valid, though altering 'index' by manually changing the drop down is invalid ?

Comment: When the dataprovider is completely replaced, none of the items within it are selected.  The selectedItem was in a _different_ ListCollectionView, and hence there is no way to know that the exact same string in a totally new ListCollectionView was the one you wanted selected. So the selectedItem will be right the first time, but on subsequent updates it should be null.

Comment: Two-way binding does not, in itself, break MVC. For instance, if a View has a subcomponent which is changed based on the properties of the main View and the subcomponent changes _view_ State, then you might well use two-way binding to propogate that change in state back to the main component's properties.

Comment: MVC means that you have a strict deliniation between the responsibilities of each component. The model is strictly there as a data store, and has no knowledge of the View or Controller.  The View only displays data and _requests_ changes to it. It only gets the exact data it needs to display or enable edits to. The Controller makes changes to the data based on the requests by the View. Sometimes Controllers know about Views, sometimes they don't, depending on the implementation.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply

Looks like what I want won't work with binding, I've got it working with manually creating binding functions using the FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT event.

Thanks for the clarification, I'll keep those things in mind.